# Removing a sparsity constraint in operator bound

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfies 
$$
\sqrt{1 - \delta} \|x\|_2 \leq \|Ax\|_2 \leq \sqrt{1 + \delta} \|x\|_2
$$
for all $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$ with exactly $s$ non-zero coordinates.

Apparently, then for *any* $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$, 
$$
\|Ax\|_2  \leq \sqrt{1 + \delta}\left(\|x\|_2 + \frac{\|x\|_1}{\sqrt{s}}\right).
$$
I tried showing this by splitting the support of $x$ into disjoint sets, but couldn't match the second term. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is $\sqrt s$?

Comment: @xpaul as stated above, the first pair of inequalities hold for all $x$ with exactly $s$ non-zeros.